# Gradle + Eclipse - new actual console window?

Tags: gradle

For a specific gradle task, I would like to start a new actual console window, not the one contained by Eclipse.  I'm trying to making it run on Windows first, using "task cmd(type:Exec) {...}".  But it shows in Eclipse - Console window instead.

Can I disable the Eclipse - Console for just this task?